# What is the difference between writing $(window).scroll(); inside document.ready() and outside it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the difference between the below two codes?

1.

```
$j(document).ready(function() {
    $j(window).scroll(function() {
        // do something
    });
});
```

2.

```
$j(window).scroll(function() {
    // do something
});
```

Comment: First will work only when DOM is ready

Answer (score 2):

The code

```
$j(document).ready(function() {
    $j(window).scroll(function() {
        // do something
    });
});
```

only executes when the DOM has loaded, in contrast to

```
$j(window).scroll(function() {
   // do something
});
```

which executes as soon as the javascript execution reaches this part of code

Read for further information: https://api.jquery.com/ready/.

Answer (score 0):

`$(document).ready(function(){ });` only runs when everything is loaded, this means including images and iframes. So when you scroll you actually scroll to the point that you want to go to. In case the images are not loaded yet, you will scroll to a part, and then the images load which makes the page change and move element, which then can be add a different place then where you initially scrolled to.

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: This is misleading. `$(document).ready(function(){ })` excutes when the DOM is ready (when all the DOM elements are created) not when everything is loaded. `$(window).on('load', function() {});` executes when the page finishes loading (ex: when the images have loaded).

Comment: You're right. I'm sorry, $(document).ready(function(){ }) executes when JavaScript is ready to run.